# Selenium WebDriver: socket.error: Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to run Selenium WebDriver using PhantomJS.

Whenever I try execute:

```
from selenium import webdriver
x = webdriver.PhantomJS()
x.get('any address')
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 176, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 350, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 382, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Does anyone have any idea about what might be going on?  I was unable to make much sense of what was going on in socket.py, and can't seem to track down __socket.pyd.  This error is happening on a local machine (OS X).

Comment: You're not using `urllib` by chance are you? (Assuming what you've shown us isn't your whole code. It might be though.)

Comment: No, the only module I've imported is selenium.webdriver

Comment: Hmmmm. I found [this issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/171) on Github. It sounds really similar to yours. I don't know all that much about what's 'under the hood' with respect to Selenium. But this might have something to do with it, I also found similar issues within different environments (CURL, json, etc) on other forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install selenium==2.3.7
```

Apparently, the latest Selenium version doesn't work well with phantomjs 1.9.2.